# Send PhpWord file as email attachment

Tags: php, email-attachments, phpword

What is the correct way to generate an email attachment with PhpWord?
I tried multiple ways but I get a corrupt file with size 1kb. If I trigger a download of the file instead, the file is OK.

```
$fileName = 'file.docx';
$fileAttachment = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'PHPWord');
$template->saveAs($fileAttachment);
$contentType = "application/octet-stream";

$notification
    ->setTemplate("template", $templateParams)
    ->setSubject($this->_("Email subject"))
    ->addRecipient("to", $email, $email)
    ->addAttachment($fileName, $fileAttachment, $contentType);
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you!

Comment: What is notification? Is that a mailing library?

Comment: It's my custom class. Other notifications are attached without a problem, so it's just a problem with PhpWord

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use [file_get_contents](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) function to read the contents of the file and then pass it as the second parameter to the `addAttachment()` method:

```
$fileAttachmentContent = file_get_contents($fileAttachment);
$notification
    ->setTemplate("template", $templateParams)
    ->setSubject($this->_("Email subject"))
    ->addRecipient("to", $email, $email)
    ->addAttachment($fileName, $fileAttachmentContent, $contentType);
```

Answer (score 1):

PHPWord is for generating Word documents, but it does not send mails.
You can combine it with any PHP mailer library. This is a sample on how to do it using [SwitfMailer](https://swift-mailer.com/en/):

```
<?php
require_once '[...]/phpword/src/PhpWord/Autoloader.php';
require_once '[...]/swiftmailer/lib/swift_required.php';

// create a new document with phpWord
$phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();
$section = $phpWord->addSection();
$text = $section->addText("Here your text...");

// Use Swift Mailer to create an attachment object...
$attachment = new Swift_Attachment(
    $phpWord->save(),
    'file.docx',
    'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'
);
// ...and send the email
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.yoursmtp.com', 25);
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Here your subject')
    ->setFrom(['sender@sdomain.net' => 'Sender Name'])
    ->setTo(['receiver@rdomain.org' => 'Receiver Name'])
    ->setBody('Here the body message...')
    ->attach($attachment);
$result = $mailer->send($message);
```

You can use any other mail library you like. Or even use the PHP mail() function, but is more tricky to set the mail headers properly.